# How to force to do when button clicked from other activity

Tags: java, android

I want to toDo() work App.class (AllActivity) when button clicked from other example.class.(Activity)

```
public class Otherclass extend AppCompatActivity{

    Button example = (Button)findViewById(R.id.option_language);
            example.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    example.isChecked();
                }
            });
}

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ToDo();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        toDo();
    }

    public void toDo() {
        if(new OtherClass().example.isChecked()) {
           // To do something.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to do it. But, I got java.lang.NullPointerException: .isChecked()' on a null object reference

Comment: Other class is activity. It will not exist when application onCreate is triggered. You cannot create this class with 'new' acitvities can be only started with intents.

Comment: Better to use an interface in this scenario. It will help to let you know if something happened in another activity

Comment: best way is using EventBus, check about it, its very easy and would fulfill your requirement

Comment: A possible solution would be to make toDo() static and encapsulate it in a non-activity class (this is not required, but it is good practice). But it depends a lot on what you want to to. What you're doing is bad design, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **bad behavior** that you implemented.

If you want to check whether the example button is clicked or not. Simply take a boolean flag in Your `App` class, and set it's value on the button click.

And if you wish to pass this flag from one activity to another simply use intent for it.

```
public class Otherclass extend AppCompatActivity{

    Button example = (Button)findViewById(R.id.option_language);
            example.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    App.setIsChecked(true);
                }
            });
}

public class App extends Application {
    public static boolean isChecked = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ToDo();
    }

    public void setIsChecked(boolean isChecked) {
            this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        toDo();
    }

    public void toDo() {
        if(isChecked) {
           // To do something.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getintent() is deprecated. I can not use it. I don't know why.

Comment: Where are you trying to `getIntent()`?

Comment: Now, I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Otherclass extend AppCompatActivity{
static Boolean checked=false;
Button example = (Button)findViewById(R.id.option_language);
        example.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checked=true;
            }
     });
}

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ToDo();
    }

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    toDo();
}

public void toDo() {
    if(new OtherClass().checked) {
       // To do something.
        }
    }
}

}
```

Might this will be useful
This is bad coding practice to use static in class. Instead, use intents to communicate between class

Comment: You must declare `Boolean checked=false;` variable in the `App` class and static else it won't be accessible there.

Comment: Rightly said, I thought app is an inner class of Otherclass.. My blunder mistake

Answer (score 0):

you can call todo method of App class on any button click like this

```
    ((App)getApplication()).todo();
```